# Canary release strategy of new application

Tags: kubernetes, istio, canary-deployment

I have an application that has some back-end services and SPA front-end build in React.

I want to have a canary release with istio. My concern is how to manage the release strategy in which-

1. I pass the traffic of certain volume to the front-end
2. When the back-end request is done from this new front-end, the traffic should be passed to new back-end services.

For this what will be the best approach?

Comment: Have you seen this page?
https://istio.io/latest/blog/2017/0.1-canary/

Comment: you can achieve  this with cookie based routing in vs , https://istio.io/latest/blog/2017/0.1-canary/#focused-canary-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained in detail in istio documentation under [`VirtualService`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/).

There is also nice simple explanation and example [here](https://istiobyexample.dev/canary/):

> ## Canary Deployments
>
> A canary deployment is a strategy for safely rolling out a new version of a service. With Istio, you can use percentage-based  [traffic splitting](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-versions)  to direct a small amount of traffic to the new version. Then you can run a  [canary analysis](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/canary-analysis-lessons-learned-and-best-practices-from-google-and-waze)  on v2 (like check latency and error rate), and finally direct more traffic at the new version until it's serving all traffic.
>
> [image: Diagram]

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
    - helloworld
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v1
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v2
      weight: 10
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  host: helloworld
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

UPDATE:

Session affinity aka sticky session can be added with `DestinationRule` using hashed based loadbalancing according to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings).

Hope it helps.

Comment: that's not canary what you are describing. Canary implies session affinity. And whoever wrote that article is straight wrong.

Comment: Can You elaborate why You think this is not a canary deployment example? Istio [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRouteDestination) have the same example. Kubernetes documentation has the following [definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#canary-deployments) of canary deployment and this [article](https://dev.to/mostlyjason/intro-to-deployment-strategies-blue-green-canary-and-more-3a3) has also detailed explanation of canary deployment.

Comment: I know it is now widely documented that canary implies session affinity, but it does!. Otherwise what's the difference between Brue/Green and canary? People come up with cumbersome explanations, and the only substantial difference is that. You chose some users randomly, and you keep them on the version 2.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me. It was really helpful. Also what my concern is that using the header seems great way to rollout new version. But i want to implement a circuit breaker in it too. Like if my backend service have issue then the same circuit breaker should work for both frontend and backend service. Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK, Circuit breaker affects only service it is applied to. So even same circuit breaker configuration will lock only one host on a service if it is triggered.